# Calculate the first and second moment of high-order polynomial exponential family

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, exponential-family

Suppose that X is from the density
$$
f(x, \lambda, \mu)=(\lambda / C) e^{-\lambda^4(x-\mu)^4}, \quad \text { for all } \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad C=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(1 / 4)
$$
where $\theta=(\lambda, \mu) \in(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ is unknown.

How would I calculate $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$?

This seems ugly to solve with an integral so I use properties of the exponential family.

My attempt:

Step 1) Show that it is an exponential family

$f(y, \lambda, \mu) = \frac{1}{C}exp\{-\lambda^4 x^4 + 4x^3\mu \lambda^4 - 6x^2\mu^2 \lambda^4 + 4x\mu^3\lambda^4 - \lambda^4 \mu^4 + ln(\lambda)\}$

since we can write this in the form:

$h(x)exp\{\eta(\mu, \lambda)^T T(X) - B(\mu, \lambda)\}$ or $h(x)exp\{\eta^TT(X) - A(\eta)\}$

where,

$h(x) = \frac1c$,

$\eta_1(\mu, \lambda) = -\lambda^4$, $~\eta_2(\mu, \lambda) = 4 \mu\lambda^4$, $~\eta_3(\mu, \lambda) = -6 \mu^2\lambda^4$, $~\eta_4(\mu, \lambda) = 4 \mu^3\lambda^4$,

$T_1(x) = x^4$, $~T_2(x) = x^3$, $~T_3(x) = x^2$, $~T_4(x) = x$,

$B(\mu, \lambda) = \lambda^4 \mu^4 - ln(\lambda)$

it is a regular class of the exponential family. It has rank 4 because it has 4 linearly independent statistics and it is full rank.

Step 2) Make use of the property for the canonical exponential family, $E(T(X)) = A'(\eta)$

$\eta_1 = -\lambda^4$, $~\eta_2 = 4 \mu \lambda^4$, $~\eta_3 = -6 \mu^2 \lambda^4$, $~\eta_4 = 4 \mu^3 \lambda^4$

and so here I am not sure how to parametrize $A(\eta)$, my attempt:

$A(\eta)$ = $\lambda^4 \mu^4 - ln(\lambda) = (\frac{\eta_4}{4})(\frac{-3\eta_4}{2\eta_3}) - \frac14ln(-\eta_1) = \frac{-3\eta_4^2}{8\eta_3} - \frac14ln(-\eta_1)$

$\frac{\partial A(\eta)}{\partial \eta_4} = E(X) = \frac{-3\eta_4}{4\eta_3} = \frac{\mu}{2}$?

$\frac{\partial A(\eta)}{\partial \eta_3} = E(X^2) = \frac{3\eta_4^2}{8\eta_3^2} = \frac{- \mu^2}{4}$?

This seems wrong and I get differing solutions when I reparametrize the $A(\eta)$.

Comment: These expectations can readily be found by direct integration or by means of the moment generating function.  You should first simplify by choosing units of measurement in which $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=0.$